# How to restore a new instance in android/java

Tags: java, android

I am implementing a reward video (key in code below is test for reward video) in my application and I am having an issue with it.

I am determining when the video appears based on a number of clicks. Now the click count is correct so there is no issue with the count. The problem is that it only works for one of the if statements. What I mean is thisL

- I start on 0 click count and navigate to the second page where all the action happens.
- I click the 'Select another' which adds a count to the click count by +1 for each click
- When it reaches 4, the alert dialog appears and so does the reward video.
- I click on the 'Select another' button again until the count reaches 8. The dialog appears but the video does not appear.

I think the problem is because my code is within onCreate so I want to know how else can I implement it so the code does not stop after a single instance?

```
public class Content extends AppCompatActivity {

Button backButton;
Button selectAnotherButton;
TextView clickCountText;
int getClickCountInt;

private InterstitialAd mInterstitialAd;
private RewardedVideoAd mRewardedVideoAd;

@Override
protected void onCreate(Bundle savedInstanceState) {
    super.onCreate(savedInstanceState);
    setContentView(R.layout.activity_content);

    MobileAds.initialize(Content.this, "ca-app-pub-7309286809417855~8595647883");
    mInterstitialAd = new InterstitialAd(Content.this);
    mInterstitialAd.setAdUnitId("ca-app-pub-3940256099942544/1033xxxxx");
    mInterstitialAd.loadAd(new AdRequest.Builder().build());

    // Use an activity context to get the rewarded video instance.
    mRewardedVideoAd = MobileAds.getRewardedVideoAdInstance(Content.this);
    //mRewardedVideoAd.setRewardedVideoAdListener(Content.this);
    mRewardedVideoAd.loadAd("ca-app-pub-3940256099942544/5224354917",
            new AdRequest.Builder().build());

    final SharedPreferencesManager prefManager = SharedPreferencesManager.getInstance(Content.this);
    clickCountText = findViewById(R.id.click_count);
    clickCountText.setText(Integer.toString(prefManager.getClicks()));
    getClickCountInt = Integer.parseInt(clickCountText.getText().toString());

    backButton = findViewById(R.id.button_back);
    selectAnotherButton = findViewById(R.id.button_select_another);



    selectAnotherButton.setOnClickListener(new View.OnClickListener() {
        @Override
        public void onClick(View v) {
            getClickCountInt++;
            clickCountText.setText(Integer.toString(prefManager.increaseClickCount()));

            if (getClickCountInt == 4) {
                ShowRewardDialog("Congratulations!!! You have read 30 pieces of content on this app." +
                        "\n\n" +
                        "Watch the upcoming reward video to receive your 1st happy face on the menu page.");

            } else if (getClickCountInt == 8) {
                ShowRewardDialog("Congratulations!!! You have read 60 pieces of content on this app." +
                        "\n\n" +
                        "Watch the upcoming reward video to receive your 2nd happy face on the menu page.");
            } else if (getClickCountInt == 12) {
                ShowRewardDialog("Congratulations!!! You have read 90 pieces of content on this app." +
                        "\n\n" +
                        "Watch the upcoming reward video to receive your 3rd happy face on the menu page.");
            } else if (getClickCountInt == 16) {
                ShowRewardDialog("Congratulations!!! You have read 120 pieces of content on this app." +
                        "\n\n" +
                        "Watch the upcoming reward video to receive your 4th happy face on the menu page.");
            } else if (getClickCountInt % 3 == 0) {

                if (mInterstitialAd.isLoaded()) {
                    mInterstitialAd.show();
                } else {
                    Log.d("ADVERT", "The interstitial wasn't loaded yet.");
                }
            }

        }
    });


    backButton.setOnClickListener(new View.OnClickListener() {
        @Override
        public void onClick(View v) {
            finish();
        }
    });
}



private void ShowRewardDialog(String message) {

    final Dialog dialog = new Dialog(Content.this);
    dialog.setContentView(R.layout.custom_dialog);

    SpannableString title = new SpannableString("YOU GAINED A REWARD");

    title.setSpan(new ForegroundColorSpan(Content.this.getResources().getColor(R.color.purple))
            , 0, title.length(), Spanned.SPAN_EXCLUSIVE_EXCLUSIVE);

    title.setSpan(new AlignmentSpan.Standard(
            Layout.Alignment.ALIGN_CENTER), 0, title.length(), Spannable.SPAN_EXCLUSIVE_EXCLUSIVE);

    // set the custom dialog components - text, image and button
    TextView text = dialog.findViewById(R.id.dialog_text);
    dialog.setTitle(title);

    text.setText(message);

    Button dialogButton = dialog.findViewById(R.id.dialog_button_OK);
    // if button is clicked, close the custom dialog
    dialogButton.setOnClickListener(new View.OnClickListener() {
        @Override
        public void onClick(View v) {
            dialog.dismiss();
            if (mRewardedVideoAd.isLoaded()) {
                mRewardedVideoAd.show();
                Toast.makeText(Content.this, "Happy Face Reward", Toast.LENGTH_SHORT).show();
            }
        }
    });

    dialog.show();
}

}
```

Comment: you could implement a loop

Comment: Implement a loop as per click on select another button? Place your answer so I can test and mark your answer :)

Comment: no, implement a loop over the code you want continously to run. if you need your code to perform other tasks simultaneously, don't forget to do it in a separate thread

Comment: @Stultuske that won't help with what he wants, He doesn't actually want code running continuously.  He just doesn't know what to actually ask for

Comment: "How to execute a method continously" .. yeah, well :/

Comment: His real problem is that he isn't dealing with the video loading code correctly.  Which is why the dialog shows up and the video doesn't.  Probably it either needs a call to some reset function, or to reload a new instance.

Comment: Am I the only one to not figure out the code, the if-else's here can only do the showing message or loading advert, not both. Please enlighten me.

Comment: What Gabe has said is basically the issue I am having. He's explained it better :) and that's what I need help implementing basically

Comment: @Amrit, basically if the click count equals 4,8,12,16 or 20, then passthrough their assigned string as 'message to appear in the dialog. Once the user selects ok in the dialog then the reward video should appear. If it doesn't meet those if conditions then it checks if the click count total divides by three, if so then display an interstitial ad. That's the concept basically